# is there a website like coinbase i can buy ether at?

Tags: exchanges

I would like to buy ether but i don't know of any legitimate websites like Coinbase for trading ether. I would like to buy ether with dollars. Does anyone know of a website i can go to, to buy ether with US dollars?

Comment: GDAX.com
Owned by coinbase.com